# Create a script that will open a file for editing

Tags: linux, bash

Create a script that will open a file for editing

1.If no argument is
given it will ask the user for a file name otherwise, it will open a file for
editing.

1. If the file already
   exist it will be opened for editing.
2. If a file does not exist
   it will open a file with the following settings

   #!/bin/bash already
   written on it

default permissions will be updated to –rwx------

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Which question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the editor is `vi`, you don't need a script. Just `vi filename` will do as you want.  Then set `umask` to set files creation permission as you require.

However if you really want to script this:

```
input_file=${1}

## Check file exists

if [ ! -f ${input_file} ]
then
   ## Doesnt exist - create empty file and set permission

   > ${input_file}
   chmod 700 ${input_file}
fi

## Edit the file

vi ${input_file}
```

Comment: Don't assume the desired editor is `vi`, query the user's environment.  Eg: `${EDITOR-vi} "${input_file}"`  (Note that this is a case where you do not want to quote ${EDITOR}, since it is fairly common for people to put arguments in the value)